# Correct html5 boolean attribute syntax?

Tags: html, standards

What is the correct (or suggested) syntax for boolean html attributes? For example which one of the following should I use?

```
<input type="text" disabled>
<input type="text" disabled="disabled">
<input type="text" disabled="true">
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to enter only Boolean like 0 or 1 in input field .
Following is the correct way :-

```
<form>
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="1">
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: The question is about the formatting of the attributes for the input tag, not what input tag will work for entering a boolean.